# String manipulation with awk

Tags: unix, awk

I am looking to manipulate the below data, able to do it with sed but not with AWK. Since dealing with multiple files I believe performance would be better with AWK.

Search has to be with CLASSA

1.Input data:

`[CLASSA        ] SXX 785.9`

Expected Output:

```
SXX785,9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print second last and last column in rows which contain `CLASSA` with GNU awk:

```
awk '/CLASSA/{gsub("\\.",",",$NF); print $(NF-1) $NF}' file
```

Output:

```
SXX785,9
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)